# git deploy with build step

Tags: git, deployment

I'm using git for my source code, and would like to introduce some automated deployment from the commandline.

My folder structure is

```
/app
/build
/tests
```

and I've got a build-step that I run that populates the build folder.

Ideally I would like to *just* deploy the build folder, and would like this to be on a deployment branch (e.g. test/uat/live).  Is there a way I can structure my repository to achieve this, or should I use sub-modules for the deployment tracking?

i.e. a workflow of

```
 git clone ...
 do work on master (or branch and merge to master)
 git commit
 make 
 git deploy live
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't version your build (you just rebuild it on demand from a specific version of your source whenever you need it)

Second, '`live`' doesn't have to be a branch or even a git repo: it should reference an *environment* (another directory, or a remote server on which you want to deploy your app).
So '`git deploy`' shouldn't exist: '`deploy`' (ie your custom deploy script) should be able to take whatever is in build and deploy it on the right environment.

That said, if you want to keep the fact that such commit has been build and deployed on (for instance) live, then you can add a git command to your deploy script: add a [`git notes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) to your commit (from which you are building).